# Using fgets and puts to read and print a file not working

Tags: c, file, fgets, puts

I wrote this piece if code below to read a text file that says:
It was the best of times,
it was the worst of times,
it was the age of wisdom.

When I run my code nothing seems to happen. Is there anything you can spot in my code that may cause this issue? (Solution builds with no error or warnings too).
Thanks :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
FILE * fPointer;
fPointer = fopen("exercise1.txt","r");
char singleline[150];

while (!feof(fPointer))
{
    fgets(singleline, 150, fPointer);
    puts(singleline);
}

fclose(fPointer);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Check the value returned by `fopen`, and please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I modify your program to take into account the remarks of Weather Vane, and I replace your *puts* by a *fputs* to not double the \n (*fgets* do not the remove the \n and *puts* add a \n) :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fPointer = fopen("exercise1.txt","r");

  if (fPointer == NULL)
    puts("cannot open exercise1.txt");
  else {
    char singleline[150];

    while (fgets(singleline, sizeof(singleline), fPointer))
      fputs(singleline, stdout);

    fclose(fPointer);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra c.c
/tmp % cp c.c exercise1.txt
/tmp % ./a.out
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fPointer = fopen("exercise1.txt","r");

  if (fPointer == NULL)
    puts("cannot open exercise1.txt");
  else {
    char singleline[150];

    while (fgets(singleline, sizeof(singleline), fPointer))
      fputs(singleline, stdout);

    fclose(fPointer);
  }

  return 0;
}
/tmp % \rm exercise1.txt 
/tmp % ./a.out
cannot open exercise1.txt
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I now get "cannot open exercise1.txt". Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @OllieParsons that means the file doesn't exist in the current directory for the program. What is your OS (Windows, a Linux ...) ?

Comment: Using windows and have the file save in the project directory. in the same place as the .sln file.

Comment: @OllieParsons that means the current directory is not the same when you start your program, may be a sub directory bin/debug/release, I do not use Visual Studio. Look at the options to set the directory when you start the program under VisualStudio

Answer (score -1):

```
int i=0;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("code.txt","r"); //lecture d 'un fichier
char codesource[500] = {0};
if (file == NULL) {
  printf("Erreur d'ouverture");
  return 0;
} 
else {
  while((codesource [i] = getc(file))!= EOF) {
    //printf("%c", codesource [i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: warning, `codesource` contains characters, not int, so `(codesource [i] = getc(file))` values a character and the comparison with EOF may not work. When the file is larger than  `codecourse` you write out of it. Et tout le monde ne comprend pas le Français ;-)

Comment: On platforms with an unsigned `char`, `(codesource [i] = getc(file))!= EOF`, code will not exit the loop due to an end-of-file condition as `codesource [i]` is never a negative like `EOF`.